# how to install eclipse in GROOVY

Tags: ros-groovy, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, everyone, I want to install eclipse in GROOVY(following the tutorial:http: // www. ros. org /wiki/IDEs) ,however, In the 2rd step-**make eclipse-project**, I always get error like:**make: *** No rule to make target `eclipse-project'.  Stop.**, I'm sure that I had set my path to the target package, so I have no idea what to do now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59098/how-to-install-eclipse-in-groovy/) by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since groovy, with catkin workspaces, you need to call the standard cmake way of building eclipse projects.

I have added an alias in my .bashrc that says the following :

```
alias catkin_eclipse='catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"'
```

But if you don't like aliases, you can just call :

```
catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidXiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4516/davidxiong/) on 2013-03-27**:
@Hansg91,I tried to added an alias in my .bashrc, but it seems no use, and when I use catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" in the terminal like catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles", I just got The specified source space "/home/tishiba/src" does not exist

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-04-03**:
Are you using a catkin workspace? Then this should work in your root folder of that workspace. If you are using a row workspace then make eclipse-project should still work I believe.